# How can I load a JS async file - OR pass a click event into an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with many social signin buttons. Rather than loading all the JS files for all those apps, I would rather only load the one file that's needed based on a user click.

So if for example, a users clicks the FB sign in button, it would load the FB.js file, then call the FB.login() function.

I can do this easily asynchronously with jquery. However, most browsers are then blocking the window.open() call because it's not derived directly from the click event.

So my question is, what is a good way to load and execute this script, before continuing? I tried with a synchronous XHR request, but that didn't work because it's cross domain.

Since the popup does actually come downstream from a click event, is there some way to pass that into the anonymous function so it can still allow the popup?

Comment: How many social media sites are you linking too? It may be easier to just put the `asnc` attribute in the loading script tag so it doesn't slow down page loading.

Comment: yeah, that looks like my best option. it works great in this particular case, but I was hoping not to have to load any of them until they were actually used. FB's script alone is 180k and I wanted to be considerate to my mobile users. At this time there will only be 3 logins (fb, google and twitter), I just like to think ahead and keep things easily scalable

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I totally agree, but 180k is not as big as it used to feel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with vanilla javascript by appending an element to the DOM:

`var scriptnode=document.createElement('script')
    scriptnode.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    scriptnode.setAttribute("src", filename)
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptnode)`

Replace filename above with the link to your script.

I'm not sure if this will still give you issues with cross-domain limitations, but if you're loading it from the same domain it should be fine.  If not, I recommend creating a copy of the script you're trying to load for your site.

Comment: To add on to this answer, after adding in the required HTML just create a mouse click event and dispatch it on the object.

Comment: I did try this exactly, but it seems that the script does not execute until the current script that loads it is done executing - in effect making it still synchronous. I will try the click dispatch, but it sounds like that would be too easy to get around the intent of the block.

Comment: You could use a promise to ensure that the javascript is loaded before the code that relies on it.

Comment: that looks like a great idea, but looks like IE doesn't support it - but maybe that doesn't matter these days - i'll look into that one!

Comment: if it works on all other browsers except IE, I'd use it. I gave up supporting IE and it's crazy a long time ago.